# Several ul inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm wanted to make a few lists like :

```
li    li    li 
li    li    li
            li
```

```html
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I used this markup, but result was:

```
            li 
li    li    li
li    li    li
```

So, I tried use this:

```html
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

but I received:

```
li
li

li
li

li
li
li
```

What should I do to receive wanted result?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```css
.list{
width:300px; //or any desired size
padding:0;
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
justify-content: flex-end;
list-style:none;
}
.list li{
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li>li</li><li>li</li><li>li</li>
<li>li</li><li>li</li><li>li</li>
<li>li</li>
</ul>
```

I used a simply flexbox. The key is `justify-content: flex-end;` which align the last `<li>` at the end of the `<ul>`. I think it's one of the most clean, clever and flexible solution, without adding unintentioned `<ul>` and without much and confusing CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hp1gdxg/)

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your `ul` to be `inline-block` like so:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>t</li>
  <li>r</li>
</ul>
```

It's hard to give you any more advice without more information on your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code. Wrap 'ul' inside a 'div' and display it with flex. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/gkkLwmLk/

```
<style>
div {
    display: flex;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
<li>1.1</li>
<li>1.2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>2.1</li>
<li>2.2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>3.1</li>
<li>3.2</li>
<li>3.3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just float your `ul` elements to the left.

```css
ul {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>y</li>
  <li>t</li>
  <li>r</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul li {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul2">
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul3">
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
  <li>li</li>
</ul>
```